# How does the same virtual address from different processes correspond to the virtual memory?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I've been reading the book CSAPP recently.
In the chapter for virtual memory, what understanding I've got is:

1. the virtual memory is stored on disk.
2. The virtual memory is partitioned into virtual pages.
3. Each virtual page corresponds to its own page table entry at a fixed offset in the page table.
   I think it means that the disk is divided into pages which build the virtual memory. Thus, each page in the disk has a unique virtual address.

And then, the book told me each process has its own virtual address space and page table.
It is confusing for me.
Assume there are two independent processes, they all cached the virtual page corresponding to the page table entry at offset 2 in their page tables.
So, How should we know positions of virtual page 2 in virtual memory (disk)?

For example, because they have the same memory form, their code segment both starts at 0x400000.
0x400000 is a virtual address, so they all point to the same space of the disk.
I cannot understand it. I consider there is somewhere I've got misunderstanding.

Comment: Google "how does virtual memory work" and you'll find many tutorials.

Comment: Put simply, the page table is the mapping from virtual address to real address (which could be either in RAM or on disk). Since each process has a different page table, their virtual addresses correspond to different real addresses.

Comment: 1st statement is wrong or incomplete, depending how you define "virtual memory". Virtual page is either mapped to a physical memory (RAM or other hardware) or marked as absent. In latter case its content *may be* read from disk into RAM and page marked as present transparently for process.